# Order of the root of an irreducible polynomial over a finite field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

Let $p(x) \in F_p[x]$ be a  monic, irreducible polynomial over $F_p$, of degree $n$. Then we know that its root satisfies $\alpha^{p^n-1}=1$ in the splitting field $F_{p^n}$ of $p(x)$ as the cyclic group $F^*_{p^n}$ has order $p^n -1$. I am struggling with finding a root of an irreducible polynomial whose order is $\textbf{not}$ $p^n-1$ in the cyclic group $F^*_{p^n}$.

Comment: The possible order of a root of an irreducible polynomial of degree $n$ is $k$ such that $p$ has order $n$ modulo $k$. Conversely if $a$ has order $k$ then $a\in \Bbb{F}_{p^n}$ and its minimal polynomial is of degree $n$.

Answer (score 1):

All the roots of a given irreducible $p(x)$ have the same multiplicative order since the Frobenius automorphism $a\mapsto a^p$ permutes them transitively.

So everything depends on which irreducible you are looking at. If you take,for example, the irreducible $x^4 +x^3 +x^2 +x +1$ over $\mathbb{F}_2$, its four roots are the four elements of order $5$ in $\mathbb{F}_{16}$. The other two irreducibles of order $4$ over $\mathbb{F}_2$ give the elements of order $15$. The elements of order $3$ are roots of an irreducible of degree $2$, namely $x^2 +x +1$.And the element of order $1$ is a root of $x+1$.

I do not think there is an easier way of telling the order of the roots of an irreducible than seeing which is the first $x^{p^k}-1$ it divides.